# Change the fixed position when browser is re-sized to a specific height

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I currently use the `fixed position` for my div which set it to stay at the bottom of the page. However, I meet an issue when re-sizing my browser to the minimum height which that div goes over my left navigation.

So what I want to do is that whenever the user re-sizes the browser window to somewhat lower than the height of my `left navigation` the position fixed is `removed` or `changed` so that it does not go `overlap my left navigation` and browser will generate the scroll to the bottom of the page where that div stays.

So how could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Better to use a class to the `<body>`:

```
threshold = 500;
if( $(window).height() < threshold ){
   $('body').addClass('fixed');
}
```

Comment: And is there anyway dynamically than 500 because the height of the left navigation is expected to be changed?

Comment: Yes, like what do you want it to be changed and when?

Comment: ok, got it. I need to get the height of that div. Thanks @Praveen Kumar

Comment: Yeah, for the `var threshold = $("#id").height();` or something! :)

Answer (score 1):

you can get   browser height by `$(document).height()` and than you can check

```
if($(document).height() > youwant){

   $('selector').css('bla','bla');
  //do you want

}
```

with js

```
 if( typeof( window.innerWidth ) == 'number' ) {
    //Non-IE

    myHeight = window.innerHeight;
  } 
if( document.documentElement && ( document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.documentElement.clientHeight ) ) {
    //IE 6+ in 'standards compliant mode'

    myHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
  }
```

now you can check

```
 if(myHeight >bla){
   //your code
   }
```